# vb.net http post cookies errors

Tags: .net, vb.net, http, post, cookies

I know this question was asked before and I was looking for the answers but I'm new to Post and I cant figure out what's wrong, on some websites it works fine but when I use it to access the intranet of the university i keep getting:

> requires the use of HTTP cookies to verify authorization information

please tell me where I'm doing wrong, this is my code:

```
        Dim cookies = New  CookieContainer()  
        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = False
        Dim request As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("http://banapp01*******/PROD/twbkwbis.P_ValLogin"), HttpWebRequest)
        request.CookieContainer = cookies
        'Dim response As HttpWebResponse = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
        'Dim cookieCount As Integer = cookies.Count
        request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0"
        request.Method = "POST"
        request.Referer = "http://banapp01.*******/PROD/twbkwbis.P_WWWLogin"
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        Using requestStream = request.GetRequestStream()
            Using writer = New StreamWriter(requestStream)
                writer.Write("sid=" & TextBox1.Text & "&PIN=" & TextBox2.Text)
            End Using
        End Using

        Using responseStream = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()
            Using reader = New StreamReader(responseStream)
                Dim result = reader.ReadToEnd()
                RichTextBox1.Text = result
            End Using
        End Using
```

Can anyone please tell me what's wrong ? or how I need to work things correctly? 
I've been studying Post and Get for 5 days to make it and still failure !
I just wanted my project to be perfect :S

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that you have not yet made a request that returned a cookie to store in the CookieContainer.

Is there some kind of login url you need to call first to be assigned the authentication cookie?

Comment: Well i have tested this code on different websites and it worked but i still can't figure out why it won't work on intranet banner. 
I have read all suggestions from other posts and still couldn't make it work.

Comment: @SalemRady Does the cookies variable have any items? Can either check in debugger or use the .Count property

Comment: Duno if these help:

http://banapp01.blabla.edu.lb:0000/PROD/twbkwbis.P_ValLogin

POST /PROD/twbkwbis.P_ValLogin HTTP/1.1
Host: banapp01.blabla.edu.lb:0000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://banapp01.blabla.edu.lb:0000/PROD/twbkwbis.P_WWWLogin
Cookie: TESTID=set
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 22
sid=someid&PIN=somepin

Comment: How (where?) to call the login url? Where to put this request, in my code?

Comment: @SalemRady You will need to acquire the cookie (from login presumably) before you try and post to the URL in your posted code. You may want to look at using Fiddler to monitor the traffic to see if the cookies are being received and sent back - http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/